# Can't load LayoutInflater in Background Thread

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, layout-inflater

I have a Fragment which has a lot of code in the `onCreateView` method so I thought I would be a great idea to place this code in an external thread. The problem now is that I have to load a layout in this thread but if I create a new object of this Fragment in my `onStart` method of my Activity it comes to a NullPointerException at this line:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

I think getActivity returns `null` but why? I create the Object in the `onStart` method. There the Activity shouldn't return `null` or what is wrong with my musing? My Code:

```
MyFragment f;

public class Tablet extends FragmentActivity
{
    // onCreate(), Variables and so on...

    @Override
    protected void onStart() 
    {
        super.onStart();
        f = new MyFragment();
    }
}

public class StundenAnsicht extends Fragment implements Runnable
{
    public MyFragment()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your onStart() method and the thread as well?

Comment: I added my post. I tried it also with `onResume()` but that does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think getActivity returns null but why?

Because the fragment has not been added to an activity yet. In fact, with your code as shown, your fragment will never be part of an activity, as you have not added it to one via a `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: Oh yes you are right that's reasonable. So I can't load a Layout if I don't add it to an Activity? Or is there an other way to do this?

Comment: @Cilenco: "So I can't load a Layout if I don't add it to an Activity?" -- you will need an `Activity` to inflate the layout. My recommendation is for you to delete everything you have done with the threads. Get your fragment working with your activity normally. Then use Traceview to determine *specifically* what is slow, if anything. *Then*, and only then, consider how best to use threads to address the slow bits, if any.

Answer (score 0):

getActivity() return the Activity current fragment is currently associated with. Please first attach the fragment with Activity.

Answer (score 0):

[Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

If you have other code in onCreateView, you can use AsyncTask with result handler onPostExecute runned in ui thread. If most of your code in onCreateView is ui-related, just leave it be there.